# Java Eclipse Mars - Deleted Debug.Keystore - By Mistakenly

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook, debugging

I made a new android application and uploaded on the google play store. Now i have a big problem. I created a new key overwriting the old one. The old debug.keystore file is replaced with the new one. Which means the old certificate has been gone.

Now i have the old MD5 and SHA1 key saved in a text file. Is it possible to create a key file using the MD5 and SHA1 i have it already ?
Google is asking for the same certificate as i had earlier or i won't be able to publish updates.

http://prntscr.com/9vho29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The old debug.keystore file is replaced with the new one. Which means the old certificate has been gone.

AFAIK, you cannot publish an app on the Play Store that uses a debug keystore.

If you mean you replaced your production keystore, simply restore that keystore from your most recent backup, as talented developers maintain good backups of their development environment.

> Is it possible to create a key file using the MD5 and SHA1 i have it already ?

No.

Comment: Which means i have to create a new certificate and publish the app again if i have to provide updates to the users.

Comment: @AmeyArora: "Which means i have to create a new certificate and publish the app again if i have to provide updates to the users" -- you cannot provide updates anymore. You can publish a new app with a new application ID/package name, and hope that some of your users will switch to that new app.